# Entity framework code first mapping property to service

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, dto

I want Customer property to be filled by a service not by Entity Framework, and I want the most generic way to this job.
ie Entity framework should care of only the key of CustomerDTO and other data should be filled by a service.

I am using Entity Framework Code First (v4.2)

```
public class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }

    public CustomerDTO Customer { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerDTO
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```